# coruppt filesystem

Tags: pi-3, boot, raspbian-jessie, update, filesystem

I have following error on bootscreen after upgrade jessie on newest version.

```
unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0 0)
```

Furthermore the filesystem had some error and was unreadable. I have fix that with fsck with a Ubuntu Live CD. But now still the same error on boot.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: rewrite the image *jessie) and restore your config and code from backup

Comment: No other way to save it?

Comment: There may be other options but given you already ran fsck it is the best and cleanest option. If you are concerned about not having a backup you can put the card into a linux box and copy individual files.